# Can we perturb a surface away from an orbifold point?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, orbifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth, compact, orbifold of dimension $4$, where the stabilisers are only allowed to be cyclic groups. Let $p \in X$ be an isolated orbifold point (i.e. the orbifold chart about $p$ consists of a finite (cyclic) group acting linearly on $\mathbb{R^{4}}$, and the action is free on $\mathbb{R}^{4} \setminus \{0\}$).

Let $S$ be a compact, orientable surface and $f:S \rightarrow X$ be a continuous map and $[f(S)] \in H_{2}(X,\mathbb{R})$ the real homology class it represents (in the homology of the underlying topological space of $X$). Suppose that $p$ is in the image of $f$, and this is the only orbifold point in the image of $f$.

**Question:** Is it possible to find a $2$-cycle in $X$, disjoint from the orbifold locus, which represents the class $[f(S)]$?

If not, I would like to know an understandable counter-example. I am not sure whether the assumption of cyclic stabilisers is important here, but I am mainly interested in this case.

Comment: I'm a novice with orbifolds,  but couldn't you take $X$ to be the Cartesian product of a teardrop with a sphere, and $f:S\to X$ a homeomorphisn from a sphere onto the teardrop factor?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it was nonsense. Of course in the product there would be a sphere's worth of singular points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is no. In general the intersection $[f(S)] \cdot [f(S)]$ can lie in $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, then of course in this case there is no such two cycle.